# Shadowbox and line color

Tags: shadowbox

Here's my code in "Préambule" of `LyX`:

```
\xpatchcmd{\@shadowbox}{\vrule}{\color{mine}\vrule}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@shadowbox}{\hrule}{\color{mine}\hrule}{}{}
```

this code gives me a shadowbox of color "mine" but the rectangular line is still black. How to also color it in "mine"?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

[image]